# Display button if checkbox is checked

Tags: html, spring-boot, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

I would like to show a button when a checkbox is checked.

Unfortunately I couldn't find a solution on the internet... Does somebody know how to solve my problem?

Currently this is where I stand:

```
<div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
    <input th:id="checkboxTerms" th:checked="${flag}" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
    <label class="custom-control-label">Terms & Conditions</label>
</div>

<div th:if="${flag == true}">
    <!-- Create Account Button -->
    <button class="green_btn w-75 mt-4 mb-3 btn btn-lg rounded-pill" type="submit" id="idBtnSub">Create Account</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works correctly for me (for the initial page display) when I ensure that `${flag}` is set as a boolean in the Java controller: `model.addAttribute("flag", true);`. It won't work when the value is a string: `model.addAttribute("flag", "true");`. What are you using?

Comment: Right know i don't use the flag in the controller, i hoped that I could implement the logic in the frontend only or do i must implement something in the backend for the logic?

Comment: You are using Thymeleaf and using `${flag}` in a Thymeleaf template. The value passed to `${flag}` has to be provided by Java on the server because Thymeleaf templates only exist on the server. They are replaced by rendered HTML (no Thymeleaf) and that rendered HTML is what gets sent to the browser. My approach is _only_ for the initial state of the checkbox when the page is first displayed. If you know that all the checkboxes are always initially displayed as _unchecked_ then you don't need Thymeleaf at all. Just use HTML.

Comment: After that, you need to use JavaScript to respond to the user's clicks in the checkbox. @Raine provided [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73625576/12567365) for that, but then deleted the answer.

Comment: Yes I saw the solution from @Raine and it worked. Know I am thinking, that the solution would be better if I just disable the button instead of hidd it but my coding therefore isn't working properly.. if Raine post his answer again i could set my Question to answered :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<script>
  function toggleButton() {
    if (document.getElementById("idBtnSub").style.visibility == "hidden") {
      document.getElementById("idBtnSub").style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("idBtnSub").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
  }
</script>



<div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
  <input onChange="toggleButton();" "th:id="checkboxTerms" th:checked="${flag}"
  type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
  <label class="custom-control-label">Terms & Conditions</label>
</div>

<div th:if="${flag == true}">
  <!-- Create Account Button -->
  <button
    class="green_btn w-75 mt-4 mb-3 btn btn-lg rounded-pill"
    type="submit"
    id="idBtnSub"
    style="visibility: hidden;"
  >
    Create Account
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).